# How to allow divs to be side by side, but overflow to be in a new row for vertical scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a cards kind of structure, and I've made a minimal example in a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/vivaansinghvi07/pen/zYMbzaY).

If that doesn't work, here's the HTML and CSS:

```css
.my-div-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.my-div {
  border: solid #FF0000 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="my-div-container">
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What I want is for the `my-div` boxes to take up as much space there is horizonally, and then, when there are too many, to start a new line and start coming there. Kind of like how text works.

What I see now is that they are all vertically stacked. When I try something like putting `display: inline-flex` in the `my-div-container`, they are all squished together horizontally.

How can I allow them to behave like text?

Comment: So, do you want multiple divs on one line until the line is filled, then it wraps?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.my-div-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.my-div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid #FF0000 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="my-div-container">
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Adding `inline-block` to the `my-div` CSS fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `display:flex;` with  `flex-wrap:wrap;` (change the elements width and see that that will wrap)

```css
.my-div-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.my-div {
  border: solid #FF0000 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div-container">
  <div class="my-div"></div>
  <div class="my-div"></div>
  <div class="my-div"></div>
  <div class="my-div"></div>
  <div class="my-div"></div>
  <div class="my-div"></div>
  <div class="my-div"></div>
  <div class="my-div"></div>
  <div class="my-div"></div>
  <div class="my-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I make the screen too small, this causes the boxes to be squished

Comment: On what screen size? I have checked on mobile and looks fine

Comment: Its happening with my real application for it, because the divs that are in place of `my-div` are bigger than 200px

Comment: @vs07 to prevent "squishing" try adding `flex: 0 0 auto;` to the `.my-div` elements

Comment: Sounds like you may want to add `flex-shrink: 0;` to your flex items

Answer (score 0):

flex is correct, but you also need to define `flex-wrap: wrap;` to tell it how it should wrap.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is a really good guide for understanding flexbox, it visually explains the options with illustrations.

```css
.my-div-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.my-div {
  border: solid #FF0000 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="my-div-container">
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
    <div class="my-div"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also if you can I recommend changing the size of the items to not have as much blank space.